# Add game loop to tornado server in python

Tags: python, loops, tornado

I've got a standard `tornado` application in `python`.

I am going to be making a game server using tornado's `websockets`.

The problem is, I need a game loop running on the server, to do things.

I could create a web handler '/startserver' and add the following code:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    if not serverAlreadyStarted:
        serverAlreadyStarted = True
        while True:
            (...)
```

This feels very hackish, and it means **every time** I want to start to server, I need to go to **`/startserver`**

Is there a better way to do this? Is there somewhere when the server starts, I can add a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just start it in the background like:

```
@gen.coroutine
def game_loop():
    while True:
        # Whatever your game loop does.
        print("tick")
        yield gen.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    loop.spawn_callback(game_loop)
    loop.start()
```

Comment: I actually should have mentioned that `gunicorn` is used to run the app: `gunicorn -k tornado myfile:app`. I don't have access a `loop` or anything.